# Loading notification image

Tags: android, android-glide

Im using the following code to load image into notification.

```
Notification status = new Notification.Builder(this).build();

 Glide.with( MainActivity.act ) // safer!
                        .load( MainActivity.localTrackList.get(MainActivity.currentOffset).getPath() )
                        .asBitmap()
                        .into( status.iconLevel );
```

But its throwing error .

> Error:(63, 25) error: no suitable method found for into(int) method
>   GenericRequestBuilder.into(Y) is not applicable (inferred type does
>   not conform to upper bound(s) inferred: Integer upper bound(s):
>   Target) method GenericRequestBuilder.into(ImageView) is not
>   applicable (argument mismatch; int cannot be converted to ImageView)
>   method BitmapRequestBuilder.into(ImageView) is not applicable
>   (argument mismatch; int cannot be converted to ImageView) where Y is a
>   type-variable: Y extends Target declared in method into(Y)

How can I be able to load images in notification ?

Comment: maybe this helps you: https://futurestud.io/tutorials/glide-loading-images-into-notifications-and-appwidgets

Comment: https://github.com/bumptech/glide/wiki/Custom-targets